# How To Put Data From DataView To XML File in C# Web Application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

i am reading data from the XML file and putting it in to data set as,

```
public DataSet GetProductsLive()
{
    try
    {
        string XMLPath = /*rver.MapPath(*/@"c:\LiveData.xml";
        DataSet dsStore = new DataSet();
        dsStore.ReadXml(XMLPath);
        return dsStore;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

but now i want to put data from DataView to the new created XML file then how would i do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do that, just use DataSet.WriteXml method [see full sample on msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zx8h06sz%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

```
public void SaveProductsLive(DataSet ds)
{    
    string XMLPath = /*rver.MapPath(*/@"c:\LiveData.xml";        
    ds.WriteXml(XMLPath, XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);
}
```

Comment: i have got it but first i have to put data from data table to the data set ,                                                                               DataSet output = new DataSet();
                output.Tables[0].Add[dtGroupedBy];  i am getting error how would we do that?

Comment: DataSet output = new DataSet(); output.Tables.Add(dtGroupedBy); Hopes it help !

Answer (score 0):

It's work

```
Dataset dataset =  New DataSet();

if (dataset .Tables.Count > 0)
 {
     dataset .WriteXml("file.xml");
 }
```

hopefully can help you!